# Flutter app not fetching any data from REST API after building it with flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I ran the command

```
 flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
```

to reduce the size of the apk (73MB -> 6 MB). But now the app is not fetching any data. What could be the reason?

The app is just showing loading screen infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```